# D3.js Giving a legend to a donut chart with inner rings

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to add a properly labelled legend to a donut chart with multiple rings. I have the updated code on the plunker here : [donut chart](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXH9lbY6wenTj1fOTwbU)

Here is the code which I use for adding the legend:

```
 var legend = chart1.selectAll(".legend")
     .data(color.domain().slice())//.reverse())
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class","legend")
     .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 190)
    .attr("y", -(margin.top) * 7 - 8)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", margin.right * 7)
    .attr("y", -(margin.top) * 7)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d,i) { return d; });
```

As you would notice on the chart that the legend is numbered from 0 to 5, but what I want is for the legend to be labelled based on the classes used to draw the chart e.g Class A, B ..

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `d3`, the second parameter of the function is the index of the element. So you can directly get any property from the data array by using this index.

Eg.

data[0] -> `{"Class":"Class A","Actual_Class":"495","Predicted_Class":"495","Accuracy":"100"}`

So try this code.

```
legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", margin.right * 7)
      .attr("y", -(margin.top) * 7)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d,i) { 
         return data[i].Class; 
       });
```

Comment: Added details to the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks again :)

Comment: What if I wanted to add text to each of the arcs with their respective values of actual and predicted, how can I go about doing that? I've updated the question

Comment: @Gbenro'Skenzy'Selere actually it should be added as a new question rather than editing the question. Please add as a new question and give me the url.

Comment: okay. The new question is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868406/d3-js-placing-text-over-arcs-in-a-donut-chart)